# h.264 MVC 3D support in x264/ffmpeg

Tags: 3d, ffmpeg, h.264, x264, video-codecs

Many threads say that there is no open source support for h.264 3D on x264 and the technology is dead. However, I am working on x264 and would like to ask the experts here about their opinion:

- Is h.264 MVC 3D support added to any opensource codecs like ffmpeg/x264?
- If it's not currently supported in x264, could I add 3D support to x264?
- Can I take x264 source code and make changes according to the JM of H.264?
- Is there any open source 3D decoder available?

NOTE: Please don't mark this question as duplicate, as all the answers I found were answered in 2010-2012 and hoping many things have been changed by now.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, This is not possible. There are a number of unfinished patches for 3D-MVC encoding.

You could try using x264 with Avisynth to do the same task as this author [here](http://wp.xin.at/archives/784) has done.

If you're on Windows, your second best bet (and also the easiest to use) would be BDtoAVCHD, which can do the same when authoring BD-25/50 and AVCHD structures, or ripping similar content with the MVC being preserved.

There are also notes on x264 licensing (see [here](http://x264licensing.com/)) encompassing special needs such as MVC and 10-bit encoding.

> Premium Options
>
> We offer premium H.264 encoding options that are not included in our standard license. These features are for customers looking to add support for: MVC 3D, Profile 4:2:2, Profile 4:4:4 and 10-bit Encoding.